# Query Table ID based on Aggregate function in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables namely Activity and Cards,

```
    **Activity**
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | Number | Amount |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |  12345 |    100 |
|  2 |  12134 |    200 |
|  3 |  12345 |    600 |
|  4 |  15647 |     50 |
|  5 |  12134 |    202 |
+----+--------+--------+

       **Cards** 
+----------+------------+
|  Number  |    Type    | 
+----------+------------+
|  12345   |  visa      |
|  12134   |  mastercard|
|  15647   |  diners    |
+----------+------------+
```

I would like to query the Transaction ID that have the most expensive amount among all transactions using same type card.

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  3 |  (ID 3 have the Highest Amount transacted on card type Visa)
|  4 |  (ID 4 have the Highest Amount transacted on card type Master)
|  5 |  (ID 5 have the Highest Amount transacted on card type diners)
+----+
```

Can this be done with and without Aggregate query ?
I have managed to query the Card Type and its corresponding highest amount spent in a single transaction

```
SELECT c.Type, MAX(a.Amount) AS Highest_Transaction
       FROM Cards AS c, Activity AS a
       WHERE c.Number = a.Number
       GROUP BY c.Type
```

But not sure how to query Only ID from Activity Table while using 'Type' as a GROUP by parameter.

Comment: What have you tried so far please also add your query

Answer (score 1):

Postgres offers `distinct on` which is very appropriate for this query:

```
select distinct on (c.type) a.id
from cards c join
     activity a
     on c.number = a.number
order by c.type, a.amount desc;
```

I've only included the activity id, but you can include as many other columns as you want.

EDIT:

If you want all rows in the event of ties, then use window functions:

```
select a.id
from (select c.type, a.id, max(a.amount) over (partition by c.type) as max_amount
      from cards c join
           activity a
           on c.number = a.number
     ) ca
where max_amount = amount;
```

Comment: But this print out only One row in the case , lets say we have Two activity with same amount on same card type. Ideally we should show both the transaction activity

Comment: @AsheshNair . . . If you want all rows in the event of duplicates, then window functions are more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT ID
FROM activity a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Num, MAX(Amount) Amt
            FROM activity
            GROUP BY Num) amt
ON a.Amount = amt.Amt;
```

Here is the fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31859b70c7b532ffe5b33de0c1f2cd88

Comment: Please do: `insert into activity values (6, 1, 600);` and `insert into cards values (1, 'diners');` Will your query return correct result?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's impossible to receive correct result in one query, that's why you may consider an option to create denormalized temporary table and then run query which returns correct result.

Step 1:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS
SELECT a.ID, a.Number, a.Amount, c.Type
FROM Cards AS c
LEFT JOIN Activity AS a ON c.Number = a.Number
```

Step 2:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tmp AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Type, MAX(Amount) AS Highest_Transaction
  FROM tmp
  GROUP BY Type
) AS t2 ON t1.Type = t2.Type AND t1.Amount = t2.Highest_Transaction
```

Result:

```
 id
----
  5
  3
  4
(3 rows)
```

You can check this queries out at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7c627/1/1).

Answer (score 0):

If `Type` is not unique in your table `cards`, you can join it first and group by `Type` as you suggested:

```
SELECT (array_agg(activity.ID ORDER BY activity.Amount DESC))[1] AS id
FROM activity
LEFT JOIN cards ON activity.Number = cards.Number
GROUP BY cards.Type;
```

The workaround is to build an ordered array for each card, but just select the highest `id`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `row_number()`

```
SELECT
    id
  , type
  , amount
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.type
      , a.id
      , a.amount
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.type ORDER BY a.amount DESC) AS rn
    FROM cards c
    JOIN activity a ON c.number = a.number
    ) d
WHERE rn = 1
```